# Jquery Date picker Default Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a Jquery Datepicker in my project. The problem is that it is not loading the current date, but showing a date 1st January 2001 as default. Can you please let me know how the default date can be corrected so it will display the current date.

Comment: Could you please provide some code to work with, if we cannot see what YOU are doing wrong, there is no way WE can help YOU!

Comment: He makes a point, we're all making up JQuery syntax from scratch.  If you include your code, we could come up with more relevant answers.

Comment: What datepicker? one of the numerous datepickers such as [this one](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) or [the jQuery-UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)? Note that jQuery-UI datepicker defaults to today so make sure your system date/time is correct.

Comment: I use the jQuery-UI datepicker

Comment: @Gijo: by default the datepicker will default to the date present in the attached control or current date; unless your code tells to behave otherwise. Can you edit your question and post the code?

Comment: I think it is simply a bug that the datepicker doesn't pick up the value attribute from the input it is used on.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

interesting, datepicker default date is current date as I found,

but you can set date by

```
$("#yourinput").datepicker( "setDate" , "7/11/2011" );
```

don't forget to check you system date :)

Comment: This may be the accepted answer, but it is the right one. The question was setting a default, which is different from an unconditional set.

Answer (score 60):

**Use the [defaultDate option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: '01/01/01' });
```

If you change your date format, make sure to change the input into defaultDate (e.g. '01-01-2001')

Comment: If you are bringing this in dynamically don't forget to wrap the result in quotation marks.
Simple stuff, but was scratching my head for a good 10 mins....

Comment: Also, if you have set the minDate option, defaultDates before that will do nothing.

Answer (score 20):

Are u using this datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ ?
if yes there are options to set the default Date.If you didn't change anything , by default it will show the current date.

any way this will gives current date

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

Comment: This did not work in my case: `$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', defaultDate: new Date() });`, I had to add an additional line with `$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "-0d");`

Answer (score 11):

While the defaultDate does not set the widget. What is needed is something like:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2

});

$(".datepicker[value='']").datepicker("setDate", "-0d");
```

Answer (score 8):

i suspect that your default date format is different than the scripts default settigns.
test your script with the 'dateformat' option

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

instead of dd-mm-yy, your desired format

Comment: Also remember that the value of dateFormat is cAse sensitive

Answer (score 0):

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: null });`

and return empty string from backend