# get datepicker to display todays date by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Using date picker field, works fine BTW. just need to get it to display todays date by default and not 1/1/0001

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDate, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = Model.SelectedDate.HasValue ? Model.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })

@using (Script.Foot())
{
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            var dates = $("#SelectedDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Also need it in format 24/09/2013, if possible dd/mm/yyy

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
$("#SelectedDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, add

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().val(dates);
```

This is how I solve your problem some times ago :

```
$(function () {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var todayDate = myDate.getDay() + '/' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker().val(todayDate);
});
```

BTW, I'll use the dateFormat option I didn't know about...

Comment: Alternatively call setDate as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date

Comment: this is returning the value as 9th feb, 2013, I need it in dd/mm/yyyy, to say 24/09/2013