# set textbox with current date onload when using xdsoft datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

i have a textbox with xdsoft datetimepicker jquery plugin. Here is the code.

```
<asp:TextBox class="spacial_text calendar" ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datetimepicker({             
                mask: true,
                timepicker: false,
                format: 'Y/m/d'
            });           
        });
 </script>
```

i want to load the current date to textbox `txtDate` while loading the page.

i tried 
`$('#txtDate').val(new date());`

```
setDate: new Date() //inside datetimepicker function- but not working

onGenerate: function (ct) {
                    jQuery(this).val(new Date());
                } //not working
```

any way to set current date to textbox on load???

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date

Comment: Try `new Date().toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) the `value` option will be used if set and ignore the input's value. To get the current date in the format you want I would use `(d.getUTCFullYear())+'/'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'/'+(d.getUTCDate())`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date(),
        date = (d.getUTCFullYear())+'/'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'/'+(d.getUTCDate());

    $('#txtDate').datetimepicker({             
        mask: true,
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'Y/m/d',
        value: date
    });           
});
```

Comment: yeah this works. but i have to set mask: false. if mask is true, this is not working. But its ok, i dont want mask.... thank you @Adam Merrifield

Answer (score 2):

The best method you can choose for html

```
  $('#txtCourseExpiryDate').datetimepicker({
                                    format: 'd/M/Y',
                                    timepicker: false,
                                    value: new Date()
                                });
```

If you are using the same in the aspp.net then please use the below

```
  $('#<% =txtCourseExpiryDate.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
                                    format: 'd/M/Y',
                                    timepicker: false,
                                    value: new Date()
                                });
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the code Below

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker( "setDate" , "10/11/2014" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

`$("#txtDate").datetimepicker({ value: new Date().toDateString() });`