# jQuery Datepicker set default value from date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Lets consider the following input:

```
04/2014
```

4 being the month

Now I want to set the default date for jquery datepicker, so I have something like this:

```
$( '.date_picker' ).datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
    yearRange: "-70:+10",
    defaultDate:  new Date($(this ).val().slice(-4), $(this ).val().substring(0, 2), 1),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

    }
} );
```

With the before mentioned value, the new date function returns:

```
Thu May 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

So the question is, why does the datepicker jumps to Jan 1946?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date

Comment: @DBS that will not work, since is part of the problem, which answer are you refer to?

Comment: There is another way to set defaultDate   `defaultDate: new Date('01/04/2014')`  try using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the context that you are using the `this` keyword.
So, instead of `new Date($(this)...` try using a selector. Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
    yearRange: "-70:+10",
    defaultDate: new Date($('#datepicker').val().slice(-4), $('#datepicker').val().substring(0, 2), 1),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {}
  });
  
  
  $("#datepicker-this").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
    yearRange: "-70:+10",
    defaultDate: new Date($(this).val().slice(-4), $(this).val().substring(0, 2), 1),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.3/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>


<p>Initialization with id selector:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="04/2014">
</p>



<p>Initialization with this:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker-this" value="04/2014">
</p>
```

Comment: That makes no difference, since this is refers to the element that is calling the datepicker, what that does is making the code repetitive since I will have to have a datepicker function for each time I use it instead of calling the class.

Comment: @jycr753 I agree with you. But using a selector the datepicker inicialization works fine. The answer is updated with the two examples. Maybe it's an issue on the `datepicker` function

Comment: I think is something to do with datepicker, since all consoles works fine, I only have errors there, when I try to set the date