# Set datepicker default date to Max date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My datepicker has restriction to at 17 years age. When I open calender default showing me year 1907. But I want to see -17yr that is Max date for calendar.

```
 $("#BirthDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-110:-18',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        beforeShow: function() {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
        },
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        maxDate: '-17Y'
    });
```

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Date picker Default Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a difference in the 'maxDate' and 'yearRange' parameters.
When I change the maxDate to '-18Y', the last possible year is selected.
The lib now wants to select the year 2000, which isn't possible because of your yearRange restriction. Either change maxDate or yearRange accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#BirthDate").datepicker({
    minDate: "-1Y",
    maxDate: "+1Y"
});
```

In the same way you can pass "-1Y" or something like this.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/44/)