# Datepicker defaultdate does not work at all

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to highlight a date on first opening of the datepicker (when the field is empty), I used defaultdate option of the Datepicker but it's literally doing nothing.

I have created a very simple input so test if this works, but nothing hapened,
I already verified my version of Jquery and it alreay includes defaultdate (since it shows me its definition)

```
<input id="date">
<script>
   $("#date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: '-2m'
        });
</script>
```

The other datepickers I created works perfectly with every option but defaultdate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Date picker Default Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date)

Comment: No, i'm not looking for the setDate, the option 'defaultdate' is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just created my own function 'setDefaultDate', i use setDate to the first of the month, and then I clear the input so that he looks empty.